# How can I accept answers?

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting answers, what’s it all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-whats-it-all-about)

How can I accept answers?

I have a 0% accept rate, and I don't know how to increase it, can someone explain how this works?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum

Comment: @Chacha: "A forum is a place, situation, or group in which people exchange ideas and discuss issues" - seems to fit the bill to me. Maybe you could try answering the question instead of getting bogged down in semantics for the purpose of deriding the one asking the question.

Comment: @Chris I did .. look at the comments for the first answer and try not to get your USB cords in a knot...

Comment: I think @Chacha102 was referring to the traditional example of a "forum" online, which is *not* what Stack Overflow is. I would assume the average 3k+ user can tell the difference between PHPBB and Stack Overflow.

Comment: Shame on you all for answering without finding the many dupes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about

Comment: @Ether I usually agree with such sentiments, but based on their rep scores, they don't look like hardened score gamers.

Answer (score 3):

You have to accept answers to your questions.

Comment: how that works?

Comment: i don't see a icon where I can click to accept answers to my questions

Comment: You click the check mark next to the answer you find the most correct or helpful to your question.

Comment: Yes, there is a button that looks like a grey V beside the vote up/down buttons on your questions. (@Meta, maybe the accept answer button should be more obvious? I've seen a lot of people mess this up)

Comment: @earlz: I agree, sometimes a button really needs to *look* like a button before people will know to click it.

Comment: @Greg, wasn't that discussed in one of Joel's articles?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the green check mark to the left of answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tick the little box that says "Accept this answer" next to the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

The accept rate is calculated over *all* your questions. To accept an answer, decide which one best answers your question and click on the tick mark to the left of the answer (under the sum of votes).